# How can I change a color scheme for Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, color-scheme

I'm very new in Bootstrap and I need help with a simple question.
How can I create a solution that can change my Bootstrap website color scheme? As example:

[link with color change solution](http://www.ravijaiswal.byethost7.com/RAV-v1.1/theme/index.html)

[and the great solution link](http://preview.oklerthemes.com/?theme=Porto)

Thank you!

Comment: You should do that in your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a bootstrap "problem". If user can change color for himself, it's "server-side" programming problem.

With e.g. PHP you must create color picker which will change any color of your template you want. You can take a look at an earlier sitepoint tutorials here:

https://www.sitepoint.com/css-simple-style-switcher/

**Edit:**

There is second great tutorial for something you want:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-amazing-jquery-style-switcher--net-532

Answer (score 0):

You can use that same bootstrap classes in your own stylesheet and change into whatever color you want.